# Simpler way for showing that : $a_n=2a_{n-1}+5\equiv1 \pmod 3 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Given the sequence $a_n=
> \begin{cases}
> 1,  & \text{if $n=1$ } \\[2ex]
> 2a_{n-1}+5, & \text{if $n>1$ }
> \end{cases}$
>   Show that $a_n\equiv1 \pmod 3 ,k\geq1$

I have solved the recurrence relation to get: $a_n=6\times2^{n-1}-5$ and from this explicit relation the result of problem is obvious,but I want to teach this to an 8th grade student(preparing for IMO) and prefer a simpler way for solving this problem.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that symbol multiplication or is it a special symbol?

Comment: No,it's ordinary numeric multiplication

Comment: 2(3k+1)+5=6k+7=3(2k+2)+1

Comment: rI think the problem's most natural home is Z_6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use induction. For the case $n=1$ we have $a_1 = 1$ hence $a_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Assume the result is true for $n$ (i.e. $a_n \equiv 1 \hspace{1mm} \pmod 3$), then we obtain
$$a_{n+1} = 2a_n + 5 \equiv 2\cdot 1 + 5 \pmod 3 \equiv 7 \pmod 3 \equiv 1 \pmod 3.$$

This gives the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

For $n > 1$, $a_n -1= 2(a_{n-1}-1)+6$, and use induction to finish.

Comment: Thank you(+1),although quite correct and precise , but more detailed answers are more welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

More generally for *any* modulus  $\,m\!:\, $ $\,a_1\equiv -5\,\Rightarrow\, a_n\equiv -5\pmod{\! m}\ $ for all $\,n\ge 1\,$ since

$$ {\rm mod}\ m\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{a_n\equiv -5}\,\Rightarrow\, a_{n+1}\equiv 2\color{#c00}{a_{n}}\!+5 \equiv 2(\color{#c00}{-5})+5\equiv -5$$

Yours is the special case $\,m=3,\,$ where $\ {-}5\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

**Remark** $\ $ Comments query about generalizations. We can view this as a special case of the following simple fixed-point theorem.

**Theorem** $\ $ If $\ a_{n+1} = f(a_n) \ $ for all $\,n\ge 1\,$ then $\ a_n\,$ is constant $\iff f(a_1) = a_1$

**Proof** $\ (\Rightarrow)\  $ $\,a_n\,$ is constant  $\,\Rightarrow a_1 =  a_2 = f(a_1).\, $ $\ (\Leftarrow)\ \,$ We induct on $\,n\,$ to prove $\,a_n = a_1\,$ for all $\,n\ge 1.\,$ Clear for  $\, n=1.\,$ Assuming $\,\color{#c00}{a_n = a_1}\,$ implies $\,a_{n+1} = f(\color{#c00}{a_n}) = f(\color{#c00}{a_1}) = a_1$.

**Corollary** $\,\ $ If $\ a_{n+1} = b\, a_n +c\,\ $ then $\,\ a_n\,$ is constant $\iff (b\!-\!1)\, a_1 =\, -c $

**Proof** $\ $ Applying the Theorem: $\ a_1 = f(a_1) = b a_1 + c\iff (b\!-\!1)\,a_1 =\, -c$

**Corollary** $\ $ If $\ a_{n+1} = 2\, a_n +5\ \,$ then $\,\ a_n\,$ is constant $\iff  a_1 = -5 $

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand your solution.

Comment: @Hamid Please see the edit. I presented the solution in a way that works for any modulus $\,m,\,$ not only $\,m = 3.\ $

Comment: I think you are using induction IMPLICITLY

Comment: @Hamid Yes, I did indeed sketch an inductive proof of the more general statement.

Comment: May we generalize your result to any arbitrary sequence modulus $m$?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi No.

Comment: @BillDubuque What for the sequences of the form: $a_n=s\times a_{n-1}+t$? Or even more general sequences?

Comment: @Hamid Yes, I added a Remark showing a simple generalization in terms of fixed points.

Comment: @Alephnull Actually we can generalize it one simple way - see the Remark I added in an edit.

Comment: @BillDubuque A yes very good. I think we all realized that in solving the question but weren't explicit about it. I thought about the issue of generalizing as wrong because it depends on the particular coefficients in your solution. I should know that "It generalizes" is a tautology...

Answer (score 1):

The sequences given by $a_1=1, a_{n+1}=2a_n+5$ and $b_1=1, b_{n+1}=2b_n-1$ are different sequences, but obviously $a_n\equiv b_n\pmod{3}$, and for every $n$ we also have $b_n=1$.